# Expected mock function to have been called But it was not called

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jasmine, enzyme

I have a test just trying to see if an onSearch has been called.

```
it("calls the onSearch method when searching", () => {
    const testFilter = {
      filterIndex: "testFilter4",
      searchResults: [],
      selectedItems: [],
      isComplete: false,
      isSearchMultiSelect: true,
      entity: "Organization"
    };
    const spy = jest.fn();
    const component = shallow(
      <FilterSelect
        {...preloadedState.main}
        filter={testFilter}
        onSearch={spy}
      />
    );
    component.find("Select").simulate("search", "term1");
    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledWith("Organization", "testFilter4", "term1");
  });
```

I get this error:

```
expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalledWith(expected)

    Expected mock function to have been called with:
      ["Organization", "testFilter4", "term1"]
    But it was not called.
```

Also here is the json of "component"

```
{ node:
         { nodeType: 'class',
           type:
            { [Function: Select]
              Option: [Function],
              OptGroup: [Function],
              defaultProps: [Object],
              propTypes: [Object],
              contextTypes: [Object] },
           props:
            { showSearch: true,
              placeholder: 'Select',
              value: [],
              onSelect: [Function: onSelect],
              disabled: false,
              notFoundContent: 'No results found',
              filterOption: false,
              onSearch: [Function: onSearch],
              children: [],
              prefixCls: 'ant-select',
              transitionName: 'slide-up',
              choiceTransitionName: 'zoom' },
           key: undefined,
           ref: null,
           instance: null,
           rendered: [] },
        type: 'Select',
        props:
         { showSearch: true,
           placeholder: 'Select',
           value: [],
           onSelect: [Function: onSelect],
           disabled: false,
           notFoundContent: 'No results found',
           filterOption: false,
           onSearch: [Function: onSearch],
           prefixCls: 'ant-select',
           transitionName: 'slide-up',
           choiceTransitionName: 'zoom' },
        children: null,
        '$$typeof': Symbol(react.test.json) }
```

Also here is the onSearch part of Select:

```
onSearch={term => {
          this.handleSearch(filter.entity, filter.filterIndex, term);
        }}
```

Looking through the shallow Json 'Select' is there and has onSearch, everything seems fine...

Not sure whats going on here and its been driving me crazy.
Thanks

Comment: Did you try with just toHaveBeenCalled to check if there's an issue with arguments and not with fn Call?

Comment: @Diljohn5741I did yes.  Same thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a debounce preventing this test from running.

This fixed it:
https://gist.github.com/apieceofbart/d28690d52c46848c39d904ce8968bb27